# Javascript array serialized in JSON enclosed in quotes, like a string

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, sinatra, stringify

In my web application, why do JSON.stringify serialize my Activity's Trackpoints array as a string? Notice in the JSON representation on top that the trackpoints array is enclosed in quotes, rendering it as a string. The javascript object representation in the bottom shows clearly that trackpoints is an array.

When this serialized activity is passed as JSON in a POST to my Sinatra back-end, Ruby parses its trackpoints as a string instead of an array of Trackpoint objects. The end result is a 500 server error, which is not what I expect.

Precision for people unable to see the included image: "The trackpoints array is a property of a complex object. JSON.stringify encloses it in quotes while doing its job. When Ruby parses the whole serialized object, it interprets my array as a string instead of an array. That's why I want to avoid those quotes."

[image: Trackpoints array serialized with quotes]

Comment: Offtopic, but looks like an interesting app you are creating. I love the garmin.com site for tracking runs.

Comment: I don't see the issue. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(var))`?

Comment: Yeah! I am parsing my Forerunner 305 data directly in the browser actually to speed up data integration in my own activity tracking system.

Comment: The issue is that the Ruby parser seems to recognize my trackpoints array as a string. Since my structure indicates that trackpoints should be an array, it crashes when it's time to assign it.

Comment: Just noticed that Firefox does the job correctly while I get this result in Chrome.